# If in conditional not working with list items

Tags: python

So I'm working with some json data.   I have 3 values

`value['src'], value['dst'], value['service']`

when I do a conditional on a single item it works.

```
if "searchitem" in value['src']:
   print(whatever)
```

but if I do the following..

```
if "searchitem" in [value['src'], value['dst'], value['service']]:
   print(whatever)
```

it doesn't match the on any of the values.

each value[] returns as a list.

Obviously I'm doing something dumb here but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the data yype of value['src']?

Comment: Refer this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-element-exists-in-list-of-lists/

Answer (score 2):

These two conditionals are fundamentally different.

Let's say `value['src']` is `['searchitem', 'foo' 'bar']`.

Then `'searchitem' in value['src']` is obviously `True`.

However, `'searchitem' in (value['src'], value['dst'], value['service'])` checks

```
('searchitem' == value['src'] or # False, 'searchitem' != ['searchitem', 'foo' 'bar']
 'searchitem' == value['dst'] or
 'searchitem' == value['service']
)
```

What you probably want:

```
if any('searchitem' in value[x] for x in ('src', 'dst', 'service')):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the type of value['src'], value['dst'] and value['service'] is a list.

So when you do `if "searchitem" in value['src']` it's checking **searchitem** in a list.

But when you are doing `if "searchitem" in [value['src'], value['dst'], value['service']]` it is checking in a multi-dimensional list.

You need to do unpacking like this to check all the valies.

```
if "searchitem" in [*value['src'], *value['dst'], *value['service']]
```

works in python 3 not in python 2

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have **'laptop', 'mobile', 'TV'**

If your search keyword is **'lap'**, and search in **'laptop'**, it will be **true** since **'lap'** in parts of **'laptop'**

```
if 'lap' in 'laptop':
    print('found')
```

However, if you use this condition like this

```
if 'lap' in ['laptop', 'mobile', 'TV']:
    print('found')
```

It will return **false** since it looks for the exact word in a list

Answer (score 0):

create temporary list using values `value['src'], value['dst'], value['service']`
and then you will get a list like-

```
temp_list = [value['src'], value['dst'], value['service']]
```

now use for loop-

```
for "searchitem" in temp_list:
    pass
```